# Chaining calls of onActivityForResult is not returning response to original Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have 3 activities :

1. LoadingInfoActivity ( A )
2. LoadingScanActivity ( B )
3. ReasonForSkipActivity ( C )

Here is the desired workflow :

1. A starts B for result
2. B starts C for result
3. C completes and returns result to B
4. B onActivityResult() method gets the returned value from C
5. B calls finish() to return to A

However, when app reaches onActivityResult() method of 'B' where I call finish(), I am not being directed back to 'A'. The app remains on Activity B even though finish() method IS being called.

LoadingInfoActivity startActivityForResult()

```
 Intent scanLoad = new Intent(LoadingInfoActivity.this, 
 LoadingScanActivity.class);         
 startActivityForResult(scanLoad, SCAN_LOCATION);
```

LoadingScanActivity startActivityForResult()

```
 Intent reason = new Intent(LoadingScanActivity.this, 
 ReasonForSkip.class);
 startActivityForResult(reason, GET_SKIP_REASON);
```

ReasonForSkip code to return to previous activity

```
 Intent data = new Intent();
 data.putExtra(REASON, reason);
 setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
 finish();
```

LoadingScanActivity onActivityResult method ( This code runs but does not re-direct me back to LoadingInfo onActivityResult method

```
if (requestCode == GET_SKIP_REASON){
   String reason = data.getStringExtra("Reason");
   Intent loadingInfo = new Intent();
   data.putExtra("CageSkip", "Y");
   data.putExtra("Reason", reason);
   setResult(RESULT_OK, loadingInfo);
   finish();
}
```

LoadingInfoActivity onActivityResult method ( We are never reaching this point )

```
if (requestCode == SCAN_LOCATION){
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        String reason = data.getStringExtra("Reason");
        String skipped = data.getStringExtra("CageSkip");
        // Process results
    }
}
```

If theres some documentation or something I've missed, I'd appreciate being pointed in the right direction as to why this isn't working.

Comment: I recommend that you switch to a fragment-centric implementation, using a shared viewmodel. `startActivityForResult()` is OK between apps (including from an app to system UI). It is not designed for chains like this.

Comment: Okay thanks for your advice. After looking into it, I'm going to take this approach